# Is it safe to use 3.9 kernel from ppa because 3.8 is broken in 13.04 on my hardware

Tags: 13.04, kernel, intel-graphics

I have a Acer 1810TZ with SSD on which Ubuntu runs really fast, except that 13.04 introduced a bug that made my laptop freeze after every suspend and nearly every boot.
Had to force a restart every time. No use.

I finally tracked it down to a 3.8 Kernel bug with certain Intel graphic chips, causes an irq storm from the i915, [described here](http://souriguha.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/how-to-solve-problem-with-thinkpadkslowd-kworker-on-linux-kernel-2-35-2-36/)

I updated the Kernel to 3.9 following the instructions on [Ubuntu Kernel/MainlineBuilds wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds). (Download 3.9 images and dpkg -i, restart)

Problem gone, laptop is running fine and is usable again. No more freezes.

Running 3.8 Kernel is no option on my hardware, downgrading to 12.04 LTS is not attractive either (it had it's problems).

Is it safe to keep using this 3.9 Kernel on 13.04? What's best advice here?

Comment: I'm having some weird lag issues since migrating to 13.04, perhaps it is the same issue? Anyway, Janghou, which of the Mainline kernels did you install? There appears to be several versions.

Comment: I am now running 3.9 rc8. It seems to have helped, I am continuing to try it out.

Comment: The latest
v3.9-raring final

`http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/`

Answer (score 3):

If the kernel works then I would keep it. I would find the corresponding bug in the Ubuntu bug tracker and keep an eye on it though to see if it gets fixed eventually. If you can't [find a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) it might be best to report it and mention the URL you linked to to make sure the patch gets on the kernel team's radar.

When 13.10 comes around and you upgrade to that you can just use the kernel that comes with it and you should be fine. It's not ideal that the distro kernel doesn't work with your laptop, but in this case working always wins over not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the commit that fixes the bug, Linux merged it in 3.11:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0ce99f749b3834edeb500e17d6ad17e86b60ff83

If you're ready to compile your own kernel then you can use the latest stable kernel. Another possibility would be to use the 3.10 longterm kernes and apply the patch yourself, it's not merged in the 3.10 series...

I'm using 3.11.1, but because my T400 is constantly noisy on the interrupt lines (the irq storm just never ends), I increased the polling time from 2 minutes to 5 minutes.